# Как правильно спозиционировать элементы относительно пропорционально сужающегося фона?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Дано:
Бэкграунд у контейнера, на котором от центра экрана по диагонали идут полосы, на конце каждой должна быть надпись.
Если задаю `position: absolute;` надписям, то соответственно при изменении разрешения экрана картинка пропорционально изменяется. И получается, что надписи висят в воздухе.
Прошу помочь разобраться с этим вопросом.

[image: схема]

Comment: Можете использовать позицинирование текста относительно каких-то элементов, с таким свойством позиции при изменении размеров окна , будет изменятся позиция элемента.
  position: relative;

Answer (score 1):

Рисуете пропорциональную картинку и ваяете такой код:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Css соответственно такой, вместо цвета бекграунда вставите изображения:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2bLp.png");
    background-position: center top;
    height: 307px;
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
}
div > div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  position:absolute;
}
div > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
div > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

.a {
    top: 40px;
    left: 20px;
}
.b {
    top: 40px;
    right: 140px;  
}

.c {
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 20px;
}

.d {
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 140px;  
}
```

Comment: Готовое смотрите здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZmmow